# Data Relationship between Provinces and Cities

Tags: database-design

Does anybody have experience or know how to correctly  design database relationships for where

Provinces ->hasmany cities
City ->hasOne Province

the problem is different cities (based on geography / province location) may have the same name. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Warning: Texarkana is in both Texas and Arkansas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
province(province_id, province_name, ...)
cities(city_id, city_name, province_id, ...)
```

This is (one to many) relationship. It is not affected by the fact that more than one city have the same name. Therefore, in cities table, the combination (city_name, province_id) is unique. city_name by itself is not unique.

Comment: what if I use a junction table?

Comment: Junction table, or "relation" table, is used for "many to many" type of relationship. For example, (student-course) relation where a student can take many courses, and a course can be taken by many students.

Comment: so in your solution the province and city has a identifying relationship?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "identifying". However, a city is identified by both: its name and its province. The relationship type is "one to many". In other words, each city belongs to one province, and each province contains many cities.